# How to remove the tiny white space between two lines

Tags: app.diagrams.net, formatting

If you were to align two straight lines, one on top of the other, such as this:

[image]

A tiny white space exists between them. Is there any good way to remove such an artifact? Obviously in this case above I could simply draw a longer line, but the diagrams I am drawing are more complicated so I was hoping for a more general answer. I also cannot simply move the bottom line slightly upwards, as often my top line is curved, leading to situations such as this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you switch off grid do you still see the line? To switch it off, just click outside the lines and untick Grid on the right.